# Postgres NPM fails to connect with second DB in cypress

Tags: postgresql, automation, cypress

I am using this NPM package for DB connection
[POSTGRES NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-postgresql)
I have two DBs that I need connection with, I am able to connect with first one but upon execution of second query. It throws an error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZNdo.png).Pool code snippet.. Any help would be much appreciated

```
` var pool = new pg.Pool(config.db);
  var pool1 = new pg.Pool(config.db1)
  tasks = postgreSQL.loadDBPlugin( pool );
  on('task', tasks);`

`db: {
 user: "postgres",
 password: "*****",
 host: "localhost",
 port: "5432",
 database: "global"
```

},

```
db1:{ 
user: "postgres",
password: "*****",
host: "localhost",
port: "5432",
database: "site"
},`
```

Comment: You need to post a [mre]. Also edit for correct punctuation and separate code and the configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

This NPM is able to connect to two DBs simultaneously
[Postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-postgres)

Comment: The question is on the cypress-postgresql library.